# mysql query select like with diacritic Turkish letters

Tags: mysql, sql, collation, diacritics, turkish

I have a token table in **Turkish**;
it's default collation is **utf8_general_ci**
On FreeBSD server, mysql version is 5.6.15

I want to query;

```
select * from tokens where type like 'âmâ';
```

or

```
select * from tokens where type='âmâ';
```

With these queries, 
result must be one unique for 'âmâ' (it means 'blind' in Turkish also)
But i have four raw result;

```
result 1 "amâ" means 'but'
result 2 "ama" means 'but'
result 3 "âma" means 'blind'
result 4 "âmâ" means 'blind'
```

that didnt i want.

I tried different collations and character sets and names.
But same results with working ones.

Any help please

Comment: can you try with select * from tokens where binary type='âmâ'; ?

Answer (score 2):

You could force a binary comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE BINARY type='âmâ';
```

please see the documentation of the [binary operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Turkish collation is `latin5_turkish_ci`. See: [Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html).

Use the `COLLATE` keyword in the `WHERE`-clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM tokens
WHERE type = 'âmâ' COLLATE latin5_turkish_ci;
```

I have not tested it. I hope it helps.

See: [Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) and [Collation of Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-expressions.html).

Comment: thanks but it gives error "/* SQL Error (1253): COLLATION 'latin5_turkish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8' */" because my default collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: If there is a `utf8_turkish_ci` collation, you could also try that one.